# Is there a name for this BFS/DFS/IDDFS-like algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Essentially, it is a depth-first search that stops at a certain depth or cost. For example, it may DFS all nodes within 10 edges from the source, then 20, then 30. The difference is that rather than starting the DFS from scratch after each iteration, I store the "perimeter" of the searched area (a list of nodes) when each iteration of the search reaches its limits.

On the next iteration, i loop through all nodes on the perimeter, performing a DFS from each node, again to a fixed depth/cost before stopping, again recording down the perimeter of the searched area for the next iteration to start from.

The reason I am doing this is because my graph (which is a tree) is split into a set of logical "chunks", each of which must be fully explored before its child-chunks can start being explored. There are a large number of nodes but only a small number of chunks; I am essentially doing a chunk-by-chunk BFS, which each individual chunk (comprising a large number of individual nodes) being fully explored by its own mini-DFS.

Now, I just completely made this up on the spot to solve my problem, and it does, but is there anything like this in the literature? I haven't managed to find anything, but I'm sure someone else has done this before, and properly analysed its performance, asymptotic behavior, disadvantages, bugs, etc.. In that case, I would want to know about it.

Answer (score 3):

I do not now of a name for this mixed type. I have used something similar too, but I don't think it is used very frequently and has a name. Often, the other algorithms make more sense:

If you want to advance slowly in chunks, Why don't you use a BFS?

Often a DFS is preferred because there you get the full traces. Furthermore, doing an iterative deepening DFS is simpler then your algorithm, just twice as time consuming, and requires much less memory.

Comment: +1 to the answer. To the question-asker, please just use a pure BFS instead.

Comment: I suppose I could just use a pure BFS; part of the reason I am using a DFS is legacy: it started off as a nice, pure DFS and I imposed the chunkification later. IDDFS -> Iterative Deepening Depth First Search; I'm actually doing a traversal rather than a search (the exact problem is to traverse a "DOM" tree to spit out HTML), and I want the output of traversing a chunk sans child-chunks (i.e. a HTML page sans child-components).

Comment: A pure Iterative Deepening DFS wouldn't give this to me. A pure BFS on the nodes wouldn't give me the chunk-by-chunk crawl, without some graph-augmenting gymnastics to lengthen the path between chunk, and there wouldn't be a nice clean "this chunk is complete, haven't started traversing children" moment (which i happen to need). I could use something like dijkstras and weight the edges to ensure a chunk-by-chunk traversal, but that doesn't seem very much simpler (though i could be wrong, haven't tried).

Comment: I think dijkstra wouldn't do better, and you would additinally need memory for the weights and get the weights somehow attached to the nodes (in another traversal? ;)

Comment: I agree with you: In rare occasions, you do need a traversal order different from DFS and BFS. I once designed a model checking algorithm that needed to fully traverse depth n before depth n+1 (with a certain definition of depth), but construct paths (i.e. do DFS) within the chunks. I couldn't find a concise name either, so I just called it incremental DFS and described what I meant by that (see http://www.springerlink.com/content/h506742168517030/).